# HighCharts Series Space

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

Hi im trying to remove an empty space between series.

Im using Highcharts with react.

I got a dynamic chart area and i need to remove the gap between the walls.

See the example below

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/dczv0u53/13/

Code:

```
    xAxis: {
        tickPositions: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    },
    
    series: [
    {
        groupPadding: 1,
        type: `area`,
                data: [
            [0, 1],
            [1, 3],
            [2, 2],
            ],
        states: {
          inactive: {
            opacity: 0.8
          }
        }
      },
          {
        type: `area`,
        groupPadding: 1,
                data: [
            [5, 4],
            [8, 3],
            [10, 3]
        ],
        states: {
          inactive: {
            opacity: 0.8
          }
        }
      },
    
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `breaks`:

```
  xAxis: {
    ...,
    breaks: [{
      from: 2,
      to: 5,
      breakSize: 0
    }]
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tb4czrfx/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.breaks